# Online course for numerical methods/analysis of PDEs

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations

Could anybody recommend an online course for implementing numerical methods to solve PDEs which can supplement reading? This is with a view to writing an implementation to solve the Monge-Ampere equation.

I have taken basic courses in numerical analysis and PDEs before, so it would be nice to refresh my memory and solve some simpler problems first. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already took a course in numerical analysis before, you should be able to follow Gilbert Strang's lectures

- [Computational Science and Engineering I](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-085-computational-science-and-engineering-i-fall-2008/)
- [Mathematical Methods for Engineers II](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-086-mathematical-methods-for-engineers-ii-spring-2006/)

Comment: Thanks. Happens to be one of my favourite lecturers too!